# Rails route accetping http and json requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest

I'm creating a REST api using rails, and I have a simple question related to Routes and how to accept requests for my api.

In my routes file I have the following code:

```
namespace :api do
   namespace :v1 do
      resources :productOp, :path => "product", :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
   end
end
```

With this code, if I go to the url in a web browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/product
```

it works ok. In other hand it only accept post in json format

If I remove the ":defaults => { :format => 'json' }" I can't open the same url in a web browser, I receive a 406 http message, because it try to find my #index HTML.

Can anyone explain for me why it happend when I remove the ":defaults => { :format => 'json' }"?
And how can I make an API that accepts http post request and json?

Just to add information, my controller always respond in json format, for that I included in my controller "respond_to :json" in the first line.

Comment: What does your action look like?

Answer (score 1):

When you have the defaults hash there, you're telling rails to make the request a JSON by default, whether you specify it or not. By removing it, rails won't do this, so when you try to navigate to the page yourself, rails will assume it to be an HTML request which will then fail if you're not handling it.

**Forgot**

In your controller action, you probably aren't telling rails that it can also return HTML. If it will ONLY return JSON then rails is right in not working correctly, but note that it's not saying it can't be found, you're getting 406 not 404.

Try something like :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @whatever }
  format.html {}
end
```

The html will then simply render your index view, and the json request will return whatever you want in JSON

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work, if I do this, i receive a template missing message... its trying to look into the views folder when I do my request, instead of show the json

Comment: That's right if you're doing a standard URL request. Doing that will cause rails to assume that you want HTML, and the `format.html` will trigger. If you want to run the URL request AND get JSON back, then just request the URL `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/product.json` and you should get JSON back instead :)